# AJAX $_FILES and $_POST simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, file-upload

I am trying to add products to a database, along with some pictures, server-side is PHP. I want to upload everything asynchronously via AJAX. I want the pictures saved in a directory name after the product id ( `thumbs/productID` ).

The first part, which is submiting the product information and retrieving its id is done. However, when uploading the files, I can't upload both files and strings, to inform my script in which folder to save. I can however send only the files.

Is there any way to send both files and text at the same time? Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('#register-product').on('submit', function ( evt ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var i = 0, len = document.getElementsByName("images").length-1, reader, file;
    var myFiles = document.getElementsByName("images");
    // Adds all files to formdata
    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        file = myFiles[i].files[0];
        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            if ( window.FileReader ) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
            if (formdata) {
                formdata.append("images[]", file);
            }
        }   
    }
    // Send data to the server.
    if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            // data: formdata, // This is correct
            data: {formdata, id: 1}, // This doesn't work
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append another value to your formdata:

```
//...
formdata.append("id", 1);
if (formdata) { //...
```

You can access it as you wont through $_POST["id"].

Answer (score 1):

You can´t not send files with AJAX post request.

The header data for the files will not be sent.

So you need to do some iframe tricks or use the file API.